# With Azure logic apps When blob is Added or Modified how to get filename of uploaded file?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I need to get the file name of a file when it is uploaded to blob storage using Logic Apps. I'm new to Logic Apps and this seems like it should be easy but I'm not having any luck.

To try and find the filename I'm sending what's available to me in an email. I will eventually use the filename as part of an http post to another service.

The logic app is triggered as it should be when I upload but I do not get any data in my email for the items I chose. I am not uploading to a subfolder. I've looked at code views and searched other post but not finding a solution. Any help most appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Inbuilt `When a blob is added or modified in Azure Storage` connector, try using  `When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)` and add `List of Files Display Name` connector in order to get the file name.

**Here are the screenshots**
[image]

[image]

**Here is the overall Logic app flow**

[image]

**Here is the screenshot from my outlook**

[image]